# Populating listbox with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to populate listbox with data.

I was convinced my below code below is right, but clearly not.

```
List5.RecordSource = " SELECT TOP " & Me.Text9.Value & " RTI.CRN, Sum(RTI.Credit) AS Credit, Count(RTI.CRN) AS [Count]FROM RTI GROUP BY RTI.CRN ORDER BY Sum(RTI.Credit) DESC;"
```

The error I receive is:

> Method or data member not found

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the type of List5? Is there exist method or member of List5 with the name RecordSource?

Comment: Add a space before `FROM`, remove leading space, check if you really have `List5` listbox, Text9 textbox and use Nz(Me.Text9,0), otherwise SQL will be invalid if Text9 is empty.

Comment: You might want to add Me. List5.RecordsSource to refer to the control on the form rather than the trying to refer to a field

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I am using Me.List5.RecordSource = "SELECT TOP " & Nz(Me.Text9.Value, 0) & " RTI.CRN, Sum(RTI.Credit) AS Credit, Count(RTI.CRN) AS [Count] FROM RTI GROUP BY RTI.CRN ORDER BY Sum(RTI.Credit) DESC;"

Comment: When it debugs its not liking the .recordsource at the start for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that a list box does not have a .recordsource It has a **RowSource**

Answer (score 0):

You miss a space between [Count] and FROM.